# Access contract using instance vs Interface

Tags: contract-invocation, interfaces

Assume I have deployed `ContractA` and want to call the function `updateX`. I can use create an instance of the `ContractA` or I can use an interface. When you use which one?
Both `updateXFromB` and `updateXFromBUsingInterface` works perfectly fine...

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


interface IContract {
    function updateX(uint _x) external;
}

contract ContractA{ 
    uint public x;

    function updateX(uint _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }
}


contract B {
    function updateXFromB(address _A, uint _x) public {
        ContractA c = ContractA(_A);
        c.updateX(_x);
    }

    function updateXFromBUsingInterface(address _A, uint _x) public {
       IContract(_A).updateX(_x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see a difference because you are on the same file when you deploy.

If you had separated `contractA` and `B` into two file and deployed contractA and tried to call a function `updateX` from contract B using an instance, your code would give an error. However, interface option would work just fine. Use interface when you don't have access to the code (you need function signature and contract address). Otherwise, you need to copy `contractA` to your contract B.

In a way,interface brings you the functionality without increasing the complexity (You don't need to copy the function).